# how to combine dataframes having multiple rows with index of 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes that have multiple rows with index of 0. I was trying to combine both but I am getting only one row. How can I get all rows?

```
Df1
IDD INN
0  1400.0
IDD INN
0 1500.0

Df2

FAD INN
0  4200.0
FAD INN
0  2400.0
```

I am using below statement to combine but I see only row in output

```
import pandas as pd

result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')
```

output:

```
IDD INN                 FAD INN
0 1500.0                 2400.0
```

Below is the constructor:

```
{'IDD INN': {0: 1500.0}}
{'FAD INN': {0: 2400.0}}
```

Comment: result = pd.concat([df1, df2])

Comment: Please re-format your question. It is unclear what your dataframe looks like.

Comment: Please provide the constructor of dataframe: `print(df1.head().to_dict())` and same for `df2`.

Comment: Added constructor

Answer (score 0):

Do you need `join`?

```
>>> df1.join(df2, how='outer')
   INDIVIDUAL DEDUCTIBLE INN  FAMILY DEDUCTIBLE INN
0                     1400.0                 4200.0
0                     1400.0                 2400.0
0                     1500.0                 4200.0
0                     1500.0                 2400.0
```

Setup:

```
>>> df1
   INDIVIDUAL DEDUCTIBLE INN
0                     1400.0
0                     1500.0

>>> df2
   FAMILY DEDUCTIBLE INN
0                 4200.0
0                 2400.0
```

Or `concat`

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
   INDIVIDUAL DEDUCTIBLE INN  FAMILY DEDUCTIBLE INN
0                     1400.0                 4200.0
0                     1500.0                 2400.0
```

Comment: If I join and concat, output is only one row. which is 1500 and 2400.

Comment: It's probably because you have only one row in each dataframe?

Comment: when I print df1, I see both values 1400 and 1500. When I print constructor of df1, I see only 1500. Do you know why? and how  can I get 1400?